# Getting a USA Visa with unspent UK Criminal Conviction for drug dealing

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, drugs

I am wishing to know the possibility of being granted a USA Visa as a UK Citizen despite a conviction for intent to supply late last year.

Sources tell me you can get away with this by simply not declaring it, although with that being fraud I'm actually not stupid enough — although saying that, I am convicted dd, so that's debatable.

Comment: Was the charge "intent to supply" drug related?  If so that is one of the USA's top no-nos and automatic grounds for ineligibility.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on not reporting meaning they won't find out. Also, the US (and most other nation's immigration) doesn't care even once your conviction is spent, although they may consider the time since the offence was commited a mitigating factor.

Comment: You might want to [look at this](https://www.cbc.ca/amp/1.3752278) involving admitting past marijuana use with no criminal charges while entering a state where such use is legal. The consequences of being caught in a lie are not more severe, to be honest.

Comment: @CMaster - The USA doesn't care about the UK Rehabilitation Act.  From the US Embassy UK website: "The Rehabilitation of Offenders Act does not apply to US visa law and spent convictions, regardless of when they occurred will have a bearing on a traveler’s eligibility for admission into the United States."

Comment: @Tom uhh, badly written (by me). What I mean is that they don't care if it is spent or not.

Answer (score 5):

Frankly, while being honest is the morally right thing to do, it is extremely unlikely to get you into the US anytime in the decade to come, if ever. Drug trafficking specifically will ban you **for life** from getting a visa or entry, and obtaining a waiver (essentially legal forgiveness) is **impossible** except in the case of "a single offense of simple possession of 30 grams or less of marijuana [for personal use only]", as stated by the [US Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/ineligibilities.html)

My advice is apply for an ESTA and do not declare the crime. Contrary to popular belief, the US **does not** have access to UK criminal records, however they may ask you to provide it yourself for a visa interview, as visa applications are scrutinised more carefully than applications for visa-free entry at ports of entry.

Try to find anything related to your crime on Google. If it's nowhere to be found, and you act normally at the port of entry, you will be fine, just as numerous others in your situation

The only other somewhat realistic option is simply visiting other parts of the world for the next decade or so, and then giving the US a shot. Unfortunately, however, you may very well not receive a waiver (of visa ineligibility) even after, say, 30 years - the law usually doesn't provide for it as explained above.

So in actuality, I'd say outright: if you want to have a good chance of ever visiting, **don't** apply for a visa, but go visa-free (with an ESTA of course). That said, again, look up your case on Google to see whether it's likely to be found

This may not be the answer you want, but the fact is that the legal doors (i.e. not involving lying) are shut and unlikely to open again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47983/discussion-on-answer-by-crazydre-getting-a-usa-visa-with-unspent-uk-criminal-con).